# What is the difference between Metro 1.5 and 2.0?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, upgrade, java-metro-framework

In a web service client project I am working on, I noticed that the Metro stack has been released in a 2.0 version, where we use 1.4.  The documentation is not very approachable for people not intimately familiar with the project.

What is the reason for the version bump, and is it worth it upgrading to the latest version?

Answer (score 3):

[GlassFish Metro](http://metro.java.net) consists of [WSIT](http://wsit.java.net/), [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/) and [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/). These components have been updated to new versions: WSIT from 1.4 to 2.0, JAX-WS from [2.1.5 to 2.2](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2/docs/changelog.html) and JAXB from [2.1.9 to 2.2](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2/docs/changelog2.html) version.

See also backward compatibility reports for all versions of Metro API from [1.0 to 2.0.1](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/metro.html).

[image]